# what is tomcat's bootstrap loader and how is it different from java's bootstrap loader?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

So I want to know who loads the core classes and natives for the core classes when tomcat starts up.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understand it, feel free to correct me:

Tomcat is bootstrapped by the normal Java's class loader.  This class loader loads the classes and jars under lib.
Tomcat's class loader loads the webapp (the classes and jar files included in the war).  This classloader is the one that allows separation between web applications, and also alows reloading classes to redeploy a war.

Hope this helps.